# start stop jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wahnt to write a jQuery plugin which will change the x background-position in an looped time interval.
`$('#element').pluginName();` - starts the looped action

Then I wahnt to stop it by `$('#element').stopFunction();` or `$('#element').pluginName().stopFunction();`

Is it possible? Can You give me a tip how to write it?

EDIT (my solution):

```
var LoadingAjax = function(element, options){
    var element = $(element);
    var object = this;
    var defaults = {
            width: 30,
            gap : 1,
            interval : 100,
            maxFrame: 8
    };
    var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {});
    var timer;
    var frame = 1;
    var is_loading;

    // Public method
    this.startAnimate = function(){
        console.log('start animate');
        is_loading = true;
        timer = setTimeout(loop, settings.interval);
    };
    this.stopAnimate = function(){
        console.log('stop animate');
        is_loading = false;
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };
    this.isLoading = function(){
        return is_loading;
    }
    // Private method
    var loop = function(){
        console.log('frame: '+frame);
        if(frame < defaults.maxFrame){
            element.css('background-position', '-'+(frame*(defaults.width+defaults.gap))+'px 0');
            frame++;
        }
        else{
            element.css('background-position', '0 0');
            frame = 1;
        }
        timer = setTimeout(loop, settings.interval);
    };
};
$.fn.loadingAjax = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
        if (element.data('loader')) return;

        // pass options to plugin constructor
        var plugin_instance = new LoadingAjax(this, {});

        // Store plugin object in this element's data
        element.data('loader', plugin_instance);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#start').click(function(){
        var loadingElement = $('.loading.ajax');
        loadingElement.loadingAjax();
        var plugin_instance = loadingElement.data('loader');
        if(plugin_instance.isLoading() === true){
            plugin_instance.stopAnimate();
        }
        else{
            plugin_instance.startAnimate();
        }
    });
});
```

This link was very helpful: http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.pluginName = function(){
    return this.each( function(){
        //Something cool and fancy happens here.

        //Remember you can have access to the element using the variable 'this'.
    }
}
```

will make your plugin available for calling `$('#element').pluginName()`

Now, about the intervals, you can make like this:

```
var holder = setInterval( function(){
    //The code here repeats every half a second.
}, 500 );
```

And then clean it with this:

```
clearInterval( holder );
```

The only problem is you have to be very cautious with the scope. Making `holder` a global variable should do the trick, but I recommend you take the chance for learning some sexy jutsus by reading [this before](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Answer (score 1):

you could start by reading [jQuery Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Answer (score 0):

sure, it is possible, you could do something like use setInterval and store the result on the .data of the element...if you are asking the question though you should probably spend a little more time learning the basics of js and jquery before tackling that project.